# Creating just the border of a pyramid with asterisks in C

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop, border, spacing

OK.  So I'm just trying to do some practice with simple algorithms and asterisks in C.  This is not a homework problem.  In my book there is a project that asks you to create a program that makes "these shapes" out of asterisks.  One of them is a pyramid.  While I can find numerous examples of how to make pyramid on the web, I can't find one that helps me figure out the algorithm for just the border of one.  And I have not seen one on here either.

Now here is the code I have already.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k,x,h=0;
    printf("\n\n");

    for( i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for( k = 1; k <=5-i; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for( j = 1; j <= 2*i-1; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for ( i = 6; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for( k = 1; k <= i-5; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for( j = 1; j <= i+1-3*h; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
        h++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When you run the program it should, since I've ran it numerous times with no errors, give you this shape:

```
....*
...***
..*****
.*******
*********
.*******
..*****
...***
....*
```

I keep thinking that the loop that has the asterisk would probably need more loops to determine the location of the spacing between the asterisks.  But I can't really begin to think of how to do this.  What I want to end up with is this:

```
....*
...*.*
..*...*
.*.....*
*.......*
.*.....*
..*...*
...*.*
....*
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
I am a beginner programmer.  In my first University level programming class.  We're only learning C in this class.  We've learned up to Multidimensional Arrays, and started learning functions on Thursday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint. You want the "first and last *" - so look at the loop

```
for( j = 1; j <= 2*i-1; j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
```

And change it to something like:

```
printf("*");  // first *
for( j = 2; j<= 2*i-2; j++) printf(" "); // spaces until...
printf("*");  // last *
```

See how you get on with that… this is not the only place where you need to make this change.

**EDIT** in response to the request by @KalaJ I provide complete code - once with the first and last star, and once without. You can pick which one you want to use by changing the condition in the `#if 0` preprocessor directive. If you set it to `#if 1` you get the original pattern.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if 0
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k,x,h=0;
    printf("\n\n");

    for( i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for( k = 1; k <=5-i; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*");
        for( j = 2; j <= 2*i-2; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if(i>1) printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
    for ( i = 6; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for( k = 1; k <= i-5; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*");
        for( j = 1; j <= i-3*h-1; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if(i<9) printf("*");
        printf("\n");
        h++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
#else
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k,x,h=0;
    printf("\n\n");

    for( i = 2; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for( k = 1; k <=5-i; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*");
        for( j = 2; j <= 2*i-2; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if(i>1) printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
    for ( i = 6; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for( k = 1; k <= i-5; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*");
        for( j = 1; j <= i-3*h-1; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if(i<9) printf("*");
        printf("\n");
        h++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
#endif
```

This produces either

```
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
*       *
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
```

or

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
*       *
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *
```

Comment: You know I didn't think to just make the loop for the spaces, and make the * print before after after the loop. *mind blown*  hahaha.  Thanks. :)

Comment: The only thing I have to figure out how to do, which shouldn't be hard is how to get it to only print 1 * for line 1, instead of 2.

Comment: Happy to blow a neuronal fuse for you. You have probably figured it out by now - when `2*i-1==1` your original loop prints just one star. So change the second start-print statement to `if(i>1) printf("*");`

Comment: that or I just added an if statement for the 2nd asterisk.
if ( 2*i-1 == 3 || 2*i-1 == 5 || 2*i-1 == 7 || 2*i-1 == 9)
{
printf("*");
}

Comment: I have question, how would I just remove the first character in the loop? So that it would start with asterisk, space, asterisk .Thanks!

Comment: @KalaJ I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking for. Why don't you post it as a new question, showing a picture ("ascii art") of what you want to achieve. You could leave a link as a comment here - then maybe I will take a look.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for a question. I'm just adding on to this example. To simplify what I meant... I meant to say, what if I just wanted to remove the first row of the loop of this example? How do I do that?

Comment: Ah - I see. I have updated with complete working code for either case. Not the prettiest - I just made the least changes to OP's code to make it produce either what he asked for, or what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define each edge as a vector
2. find max(Y)
3. iterate from max(Y) down
4. for each Y find the matching X then print dots or star if you intersect a vector until max(X) on that line

Comment: I'm sure this would have worked, but I honestly have no idea what you are talking about or where to start.  Sorry, but thanks for your help though. :)